# Ruby URI merging and escaping

Tags: ruby, uri

I have an URI object.

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse 'http://example.com'
```

I need to merge some path to this URI.

```
path = URI.escape('/?foo[123]=5')
uri.merge!(path)
```

And getting exception:

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): /?foo[123]=5
```

This is because some symbols in path considered as unsafe ("[" and "]"),
but those symbols ware not escaped by URI.escape.

I'm solving this issue using two URI.escape calls:

```
path = URI.escape(URI.escape('/?foo[123]=5'), '[]')
uri.merge!(path)
```

The question is: why URI.escape does not performs that escaping by default?

Or maybe there is some better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its by spec 
Check 
[issue #3457 on ruby bugtracker](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3457)

Comment: Thank you for the link, looks like URI.escape will be depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CGI.escape` instead of `URI.escape`:

```
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'
uri = URI.parse 'http://example.com'    
path = CGI.escape('/?foo[123]=5')
uri.merge!(path) #=> #<URI::HTTP:0x00000002947918 URL:http://example.com/%2F%3Ffoo%5B123%5D%3D5>
```

Comment: Note that the question mark very likely should be left unencoded.